Pydantic vs. Python 3.13.0: No module named 'typing_extensions'
I have code that worked fine with Python 3.10.12 and Pydantic 2.7.3.
I read that Pydantic ^2.8 supports Python 3.13.
The same code, and indeed even just import pydantic under a Python 3.13.0 shell with Pydantic 2.10.2, however, gives:
  File "/home/user/path-to-package/src/validator.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pydantic import TypeAdapter, BaseModel, validator
  File "/home/user/path-to-package/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.py", line 396, in <module>
    _getattr_migration = getattr_migration(__name__)   
  File "/home/user/path-to-package/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pydantic/_migration.py", line 260, in getattr_migration
    from .errors import PydanticImportError
  File "/home/user/path-to-package/.venv/lib/python3.13/site-packages/pydantic/errors.py", line 7, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Literal, Self 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'


Why?
How can I fix this?

Did you try this?

Per comment to answer below, yes. And it worked. What I don't understand is ... why for almost all other cases, package managers will install all serial dependencies of a required library. But every once in a while there's an exception like this. I've never published a module per se -- is there a manifest somewhere within the module that lists all serial dependencies, that's perhaps missing for pydantic?


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typing_extensions'

You possess two Python versions which are 3.10.12 and 3.13. The typing_extensions will only be available for download in version 3.10, not 3.13.
The problem can be fixed.
Add Python 3.13 version.
py -3.13 -m pip install typing-extensions --upgrade

As for me, I have  Python  3.12.7 and 3.14.0a2.
I tried this today py -3.14 -m pip install typing-extensions --upgrade
And here is output:
> C:\Users\>py -3.14 -m pip install typing-extensions --upgrade
> Collecting typing-extensions   Using cached
> typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB) Using
> cached typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB) Installing
> collected packages: typing-extensions Successfully installed
> typing-extensions-4.12.2


Ah okay. I use poetry, and expect that poetry installs the serial dependencies -- it usually does. Here I had to poetry add both typing-extensions and annotated-types. But it works now after having done so.
